# Populate a list (not HTML) from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, word-cloud

I am trying to use [wordcloud2.js](https://github.com/timdream/wordcloud2.js) to generate some word clouds. It works fine using the example given:

```
var options = 
{
  list : [ 
  ["Pear", "9"],
  ["Grape", "3"],
  ["Pineapple", "8"], 
  ["Apple", "5"]
  ],
  gridSize: Math.round(16 * document.getElementById('canvas_cloud').offsetWidth / 1024),
  weightFactor: function (size) {
    return Math.pow(size, 1.9) * document.getElementById('canvas_cloud').offsetWidth / 1024;
  }
}

WordCloud(document.getElementById('canvas_cloud'), options);
```

However, I am struggling with populating "list :" with the data from a JSON file with the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "wordCloud": "Manchester",
        "Freq": 2321
    },
    {
        "wordCloud": "Munich",
        "Freq": 566
    },
    {
        ...
    },
    {
        "wordCloud": "Madrid",
        "Freq": 6
    }
]
```

I know it is because my limited knowledges on pushing values to arrays. So far, my tries have been:

```
$.getJSON('json/wordCloudGWT-' + site + '.json', function (data) {



      var wordCloudGWT = [];                
        for (var i=0;i<100;i++) {
    wordCloudGWT.push([data[i].wordCloud, data[i].Freq]);
    };


      console.log(wordCloudGWT);

var options = 
{
  list : wordCloudGWT,
  gridSize: Math.round(16 * document.getElementById('canvas_cloud').offsetWidth / 1024),
  weightFactor: function (size) {
    return Math.pow(size, 1.9) * document.getElementById('canvas_cloud').offsetWidth / 1024;
  }
}

WordCloud(document.getElementById('canvas_cloud'), options);
```

console.log(wordCloudGWT); shows an array with 100 (objects?) with a length of 2 each, but the wordcloud doesn't show. I see in my browser's console an error which I assume is because wordcloud2.js is not interpreting list : wordCloudGWT as I (erroneously) think it should be.

If I bruteforce the creation of the list this way

```
  list : [ 
  [data[0].wordCloud, "9"],
  [data[1].wordCloud, "3"],
  [data[2].wordCloud, "8"], 
  [data[3].wordCloud, "5"]
  ],
```

the words are shown correctly, but this approach has two problems:

- Real frequency of words (word's size) is not considered
- There is surelly more elegant ways to generate the list as manually adding 100 lines of code

For the first point, I figured that I could solve the problem by also manually editing the list this way:

```
  list : [ 
  [data[0].wordCloud, data[0].Freq],
  [data[1].wordCloud, data[1].Freq],
  [data[2].wordCloud, data[2].Freq], 
  [data[3].wordCloud, data[3].Freq]
  ],
```

However, doing that ends with the same JS error from my first attempt.

Any hint that can help me to bypass my difficulties?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map` to format the data:

```
var formattedList = responseData.map(function(item) {
    return [item.wordCloud, item.Freq]
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/64v75enq/

Comment: Thx for Array.map. I didn't know about it. However, I am getting the same error. Trying to do things as similar as in your fiddle, I pushed the first 100 elements of my JSON file with keys wordCloud & Freq and their respective values. In the browser's console I see an array with 100 objects. Applying Array.map I transform this array in another array but with 100 different arrays this time. However, this new array doesn't look different as the one generated in my first attempt, as described in the question. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the wordcloud2.js library expects the frequency value to be a string, and that is not the case of your json data. So improving on your own example code; add a toString() at the end of the Freq variable when pushing the values. Like this:

```
list : [ 
    [data[0].wordCloud, data[0].Freq.toString()],
    [data[1].wordCloud, data[1].Freq.toString()],
    ...
]
```

Comment: Initially I thought the same, but before asking the question I tried with [data[0].wordCloud, 9] and it also worked :)